# I can't center image in HTML

Tags: html, image

Below is the snippet:

I don't know what's wrong with it. I even checked other sources. nothing has helped.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1><center><font face="Narkisim" color="maroon">Welcome to Preeyah Museum</font></center></h1>

<h2><center><font face="Narkisim" color="black">World of South Indian Food</font></center></h2>

<img src="southIndiaMap.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="South India States" align="center">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**note `<center>` tag and `<font>` tag are deprecated in html 5**

set `text-align: center` for body or put image to a div and give to div style `text-align: center`

you can try other way
for example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <h1 style="text-align:center; font-family: Narkisim; color:maroon;">Welcome to Preeyah Museum</h1>

  <h2 style="text-align:center; font-family: Narkisim; color:black;">World of South Indian Food</h2>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <img src="southIndiaMap.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="South India States">
  </div>


<body
```

exists many way for this, for example you can set style for element in css file or set in  style code  tag and put it to  tag top of  tag

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you have to do to center it, use

> ```
> img { 
>   margin: 0 auto;
>   display: block;
> }
> ```

The following snippet works:

```css
.container img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1><center><font face="Narkisim" color="maroon">Welcome to Preeyah Museum</font></center></h1>

<h2><center><font face="Narkisim" color="black">World of South Indian Food</font></center></h2>

<div class="container">
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823__480.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="South India States" align="center">
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should link the html and css...

Answer (score 0):

The image may align it in the center of itself but there is space next to the image that is not part of the image.

Try adding the attribute `style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"` to the image.

As far as I know, you can also add the tags `margin-left="auto" margin-right="auto"`.

This sets the space to the right and the left to be equal.

By the way, it is a good pattern to move everything related to design to external css files.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a style within the img tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1><center><font face="Narkisim" color="maroon">Welcome to Preeyah Museum</font></center></h1>
    <h2><center><font face="Narkisim" color="black">>World of South Indian Food</font></center></h2>
    <img  style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; " src="southIndiaMap.jpg" height="300" width="300" alt="South India States" align="center">
</body>
</html>
```